# Select the last two names in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

1. In my data sheet1, I want to use the 'Name in use' column (B) with the last two names with ARRAYFORMULA.
2. In my data sheet2, I want column (B) to be repeated with the same code next to the column A get filled

Please find the sample date sheet below  [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_AWRjexJNAcgNGsmrBKU_8JYL03UbAGeiyy4oI8B9fU/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_AWRjexJNAcgNGsmrBKU_8JYL03UbAGeiyy4oI8B9fU/edit?usp=sharing%C2%A0) 
 Regards,
Nimal PereraSri Lanka

Answer (score 0):

## Sheet 1

Your formula seems fine, just the `ArrayFormula()` needs tweaking. As noted in the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), `ArrayFormula()` takes in a range, rather than a single cell.
You would have to do something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(UPPER(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5," ",REPT(" ",60)),120)))))
```

Essentially you type in the range you'd like it to apply on. So at any moment, instead of selecting a single cell for that row, you select the range. If you'd want to apply it to the entire column, use `A2:A`. You even did it right on sheet2

## Sheet 2

Your names seem to be importing correctly once Sheet1 is done right. To have the same `code` everywhere, use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),"SSD",""))
```